# Return HTML or JSON in a Spring Controller Method

Tags: json, spring-mvc, response

I am wondering the correct way to return HTML or JSON inside the same method depending on logic on a Spring Controller method.  I have done this in .NET, just need to know how to do this in Spring.

```
    UserModel user = new UserModel();       
    user.setFirstName("Michael");
    user.setLastName("Flynn");

    model.getList().add(user);
    model.setSearchTerm("test");

    if(true)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("controls/tables/users", "model", model);
    }
    else
        return model;
```

Comment: Any updates on this thread? any acceptable anwers?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the requests are indicating which format they want using standard HTTP content negotation.   If so you can use the [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations).   It also supports selection of format using an "extension" of a URL, for example: http://localhost/content.json would select JSON and http://localhost/content.html would select HTML.

Comment: That would be great if the user knows what they want.  But I want to either return HTML or JSON depending if an error occurred or not.  Returning HTML is basically a success, while returning JSON means an error was caused.  I have javascript that will handle both situations on the client side to test if it is HTML or JSON.  That client side javascript works great because I did the same thing in .NET.  My question is I don't my the content type of the request to determine the output.

Comment: Ok, from your controller return a ModelAndView where the View is either a JSTLView (or whatever view is appropriate to the HTML templating language you are using) or a MappingJacksonJsonView on error.

Comment: Do have an example of doing this in code?  I am looking into subclassing flexjson called JsonView which will do what I need.